# Show that space with inner product $\sum_{f(x)g(x)\ne 0} f(x)\overline{g(x)}$ is not separable

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Consider the space of all functions $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ for which $f(x)=0$ everywhere, except in a countable number of points in $\mathbb{R}$ and $$ \sum_{f(x)\ne 0} |f(x)|^2<\infty.$$ Define the inner product $$ \langle f,g\rangle = \sum_{f(x)g(x)\ne 0}f(x)\overline{g(x)}.$$

My notes proceed by saying that this space is not separable. The given reasoning: for each sequence of function $f_n$ in this space, there exist functions $f\ne 0$, s.t. $\langle f,f_n\rangle=0,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I'm trying to find such functions. It's fairly easy to construct an example for specific sequences (f.ex. $f_n(x) = 1$ for $x=n$, $f_n(x)=0$ otherwise, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$). My goal is to do this for general sequences. Is following strategy ok?

Consider $(f_n)_n$ in this space. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $I_n=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f_n(x)\ne 0\}$. Let $I = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} I_n$. Then $I$ is countable as the countable union of countable sets. We can now construct a function $f$ such that $f(x)=0,\forall x\in I$. Indeed, let $y\not\in I$, then we can set $f(x)=1$ for $x=y$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $$ |\langle f,f_n\rangle|\le \sum_{x\in I} f(x)\overline{f_n(x)}=0, \forall n\in\mathbb{N},$$ but clearly, $f\ne 0$.

Is this ok? Are there other constructions or, more generally, other reasonings to show that the given space is not separable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a good construction.

Another (related) one goes like this.  For each $t \in \mathbb R$, define $e_t$ by $e_t(t) = 1$ and $e_t(x) = 0$ otherwise.  Then $\{e_t : t \in \mathbb R\}$ is an uncountable orthonormal system in this inner product.